# C string function with pointers returning null

Tags: c, memory-management

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void catTo(char *dest, const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    dest = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2) );
    strcpy(dest, str1);
    strcat(dest, str2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *str1 = "abcd";
    char *str2 = "defg";
    char *dest;
    catTo(dest, str1, str2);
    printf("%s",dest);

    return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to get a simple str copy function to work, however, when I print out dest, I get "(null)".  I tried, messing around with putting &/* infront of certain variables, but to no prevail.

Comment: `void catTo(char *dest, `: `dest` won't be modified outside your function.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value. The type is already `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 4):

don't pass `dest` as an input parameter. Its start value is not needed (and undefined) and is not modified by the `catTo` function call, which explains your problem.

Better do this:

```
char *catTo(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    char *dest = malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2) );
    strcpy(dest, str1);
    strcat(dest, str2);
    return dest;
}
```

and in the caller:

```
char *dest = catTo(str1, str2);
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `char dest = /*...*/`in `catTo`?

Answer (score 4):

> I tried, messing around with putting &/* infront of certain variables, but to no prevail.

That's a terrible way of solving problems - you should review your knowledge on pointers and value semantics instead of randomly adding operators to your code.

Regardless, the issue is that you're passing `dest` as a `char*` and then assigning to `dest` inside `catTo`: since you're copying `dest`, you're assigning to the local argument, not to the `dest` instance present in `main`.

You can solve this issue by passing `dest` as a `char**`:

```
void catTo(char **dest, const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    *dest = malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(str2) );
    strcpy(*dest, str1);
    strcat(*dest, str2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *str1 = "abcd";
    char *str2 = "defg";
    char *dest;
    catTo(&dest, str1, str2);
    printf("%s",dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, every `malloc` should be matched by a corresponding `free`. Don't forget to call `free(dest)` when you're done with it in `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *str1 = "abcd";
    char *str2 = "defg";
    char *dest;
    catTo(&dest, str1, str2);
    printf("%s",dest);
    free(dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no need for that char* cast in malloc: `(char *) malloc` => `malloc`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre still not Javascript's level of lenience, but pretty close!